# Why print functionality in javascript is not working in edge, but works in chrome

Tags: angularjs, printing, microsoft-edge, permission-denied

Hi I have the below code to achieve print functionality . The code works fine in Chrome, but doesnt work in Edge. Getting the follwing error in edge.I am building the layout in javascript in generatePDF  function. 
[image]

Below is my JS code:

```
$scope.printRepayment = function() {
    var documentDefinition = generatePDF();                                     pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition).print();
      }



var generatePDF = function() {
            var repayments = $scope.repayments;
            var rows = [
              [
                { text: "Payment No", style: "tableHeader" },
                { text: "Installment", style: "tableHeader" },
              ]
            ];
            for (var i = 0; i < repayments.length; i++) {
              rows.push([
                { text: i + 1, style: "tablefirst" },
                {
                  text:
                    "AED " +
                    numberWithCommas(
                      parseFloat(repayments[i].installment).toFixed(2)
                    ),
                  style: "tableOther"
                },
              ]);
            }
            return {
              content: [
                { text: "Repayment schedule", style: "subheader" },
                {
                  style: "tableExample",
                  table: {
                    widths: ["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"],
                    body: rows
                  },
                  layout: {
                    vLineColor: function(i, node) {
                      return "#ECF3FE";
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              styles: {
                tabletop: {
                  margin: [10, 0, 0, 10]
                },
                tabletopHeader: {
                  fontSize: 16,
                  bold: true
                }
              }
            };
          };
```

Comment: Whats is the version of Edge that you are using? Does `pdfmake.js` supports Edge?

Comment: Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0

Comment: `pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition).print();`... The `print()` method is not supported by Edge. Please check the [Browser support](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/800). Edge only supports `download()`

Comment: Thanks for the link..Is there any other way to achieve download in Edge? other than print()

Comment: Can you try `pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition).download(); `?

Comment: .download() works fine, but i need print functionality, as download just downloads and print behaviour is different.

Answer (score 0):

With refer to [this article](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/800), we can see that the pdfMake print() method doesn't support Edge browser. So, as a workaround, I think you could create a web page which contains the display the pdf content, then, calling the `window.print();` method to print this page. Otherwise, as Master Po said, you could download the pdf file first, then, print the pdf content.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a ton @Zhi Lv - MSFT, for giving the solution in plain english and then after having discovered how to do, this is what worked for me

```
var pdf = pdfMake.createPdf(doc);
pdf.getBuffer(function (buffer) {
            var file = new Blob([buffer], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            window.location.href = fileURL; 
        }); // {autoPrint: true});
```

the pdf file generated is converted into a blob and the url of that file is then opened up as a new window, shows the pdf doc and can be printed

Yet not sure how autoPrint works, will need to work a bit more